# youtube api use oauth token to get info on user in .NET

Tags: c#, ios, .net, youtube, youtube-api

I have an app(ios) that you can login with google and I ask the user to give permissions to access his youtube data,

```
func doOAuthGoogle(){
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    GoogleYoutube["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: GoogleYoutube["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        responseType:   "code"
    )
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "W2GCW24QXG.com.xxx.xxx:/oauth-swift")!, scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube", state: "", success: {
        credential, response, parameters in
        print("oauth_token:\(credential.oauth_token)")
        let parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

        //TODO: send oauth to server
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxx.azurewebsites.net:80/api/Login/Google/", parameters: ["access_token" : credential.oauth_token]).responseJSON { response in
             print(response)
             let resultDic : NSDictionary =  (response.result.value as? NSDictionary)!

             defaults.setObject(resultDic.valueForKey("userId"), forKey: "UserId")
             let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcGroupsViewController") as? GroupsController
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                    }

        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
}
```

after that I get the `credential.oauth_token`  and send it to the server that is .NET.

on the server I have the library

```
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
```

and now I want to get the user music playlist but I cant find example code for that, like in facebook that have the facebookclient

```
 var accessToken = access_token;
    var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    // 1 : hit graph\me?fields=
    dynamic me = client.Get("me", new { fields = new[] { "id", "name", "first_name", "last_name", "picture.type(large)", "email", "updated_time" } });
    dynamic meMusic = client.Get("me/music");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found my answer to my own question, 
send the access token to the server and then use web client to call the youtube data api v3 with the proper headers, the result will be youtube playlist ids , from there take `watchHistory` node and save it to local var, and use it in webclient2 to call the list items.

hope it will help others.

```
internal User SaveGoogleYoutubeLogin(string access_token)
{
    var accessToken = access_token;
    string watchHistoryList = "";
    using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,"Bearer " + accessToken);
        webclient.Headers.Add("X-JavaScript-User-Agent", "Google APIs Explorer");
        var respone2 = webclient.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={your_api_key}");
        Debug.Print(respone2);
        JObject jResponse = JObject.Parse(respone2);
        watchHistoryList = (string)jResponse["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["watchHistory"].ToString();

    }
    using (WebClient webclient2 = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);
        webclient2.Headers.Add("X-JavaScript-User-Agent", "Google APIs Explorer");
        var respone2 = webclient2.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId="+ watchHistoryList + "&key={your_api_key}");
        Debug.Print(respone2);
        JObject jResponse = JObject.Parse(respone2);
        foreach (var item in jResponse["items"])
        {
            Debug.Print(item.ToString());
        }

        }
```